# Gatsby & markdown - fetching and writing to a task list

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby

I have a gatsby project that has in its root a `README.md` file. It's content looks like this

```
# This is a title

Some random description here...

# My Solar System

- [ ] Mercury
- [x] Venus
- [x] Earth (Orbit/Moon)
- [ ] Jupiter
```

I installed `gatsby-transformer-remark` and configured `gatsby-source-filesystem` as follows:

```
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
            options: {
                name: "images",
                path: `${__dirname}/src/images`
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
            options: {
                name: "root",
                path: `${__dirname}`,
                ignore: [`**/\.*`] // ignore files starting with a dot
            }
        }
```

What I'm trying to do now is to fetch the data under a specific heading (e.g. `My Solar System`) and store it into an checkbox input form. Hence, I'd like to fetch something like `{name, isChecked}` for each of those entries in the md task list.

I tried building a graphql query like this

```
query MyQuery {
  markdownRemark(fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/README.md/"}) {
    htmlAst
  }
}
```

This returns a huge object that includes, somewhere, the information I need. However, finding that data and filtering it out is a pain.
Filtering directly in the query is also not possible because `Field "htmlAst" must not have a selection since type JSON has no subfields`

Is there any way to get what I need in this case? And if so, would it be even possible to write back to the .md file if the any value changes?